# Creating an ASP.NET app with crud functionatility but not able to create new products as the ModelState.IsValid is false

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC web app with crud functionalities and my `ModelState.IsValid` is always returning false when I click on the create button. When I added some debugging, it shows that the drop down that has the category list from another table which is a foreign key for my product model is not being selected in creating this and it says `categoryId` is required. Please can anyone help me fix this?

These are my model classes:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Unit of Measurement")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(_context.Category, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
    return View();
}

// POST: Products/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
// add debuggers to the Create method
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ProductID,ProductName,CategoryID,Unit,Price")] Product product)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Log each error in the ModelState
        var errorList = ModelState
                             .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                             .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key,
                                           kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray());

        // For debugging: place a breakpoint here and inspect errorList
        foreach (var error in errorList)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Key: {error.Key}, Errors: {string.Join(", ", error.Value)}");
        }

        // Re-populate the CategoryID dropdown before returning the view
        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(await _context.Category.ToListAsync(), "CategoryID", "CategoryName", product.CategoryID);

        return View(product);
    }

    // Proceed with adding the product to the database
    _context.Add(product);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

My view for create:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="CategoryID" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="CategoryID" asp-items="ViewBag.CategoryID" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
```

I was expecting when I click on create new product, it adds a new product to my database with the category selected in the dropdown.

I tried debugging and everything, making sure the database has the category etc.

```
FROM [Category] AS [c]
Key: Category, Errors: The Category field is required.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [c].[CategoryID], [c].[CategoryName], [c].[Description]
FROM [Category] AS [c]
```

Answer (score 1):

> " it says categoryId is required"  and " with the category selected in the dropdown."

I guess you may see the error `Category  is required`. Make sure you have selected the CategoryID in the dropdown .You can try to add`?` like below to avoid the ModelState.IsValid is false:

```
public Category? Category { get; set; }
```